# 404 page laravel Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project in laravel with admin and user pages but i need to create the error pages for admin i.e.

> admin\
>
> - 404-admin.blade.php
> - 403-admin.blade.php
>
> site\
>
> - 404.blade.php
> - 500.blade.php

How can I specify which page corresponds to each section?
Thanks

Comment: Resolve custom logic for the `NotFoundHttpException` in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` file. You can capture the `NotFoundHttpException` and perform some custom logic with a fallback, dictating which view to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All error pages are rerouted to `/resources/views/errors/(error code).blade.php`. If the page doesn't exist, laravel shows the server default. You may not have created them for it is optional. You can use the answer of @ZeroOne in combination with these error pages where you are free to modify them to your needs.

For example the 403.blade.php page. As you can see, it's easy to modify them to your request:

```
@extends('layouts.app', [])

@section('content')
    <div class="alert alert-warning  alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="material-icons align-bottom">error</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <p class="bigger-150">503 Forbidden</p>
                You don't have access to this page. Please <a href="{{ route('user.login') }}">login</a> or try something else. You may have lost your login
                session. Consider checking the '<i>Remember me</i>' button at you login page next time. If you think this is an error or a bug, please <a
                        href="{{ route('home.contact') }}">contact us</a>. <br/><br/>
                Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Ok, but i need to set 2 desing for admin and users site , i need two diferents 404 pages error

Comment: Thanks I can use blade to set the respective page in case if the user is admin , is site user or if is gest

Answer (score 3):

just alter your Exception/Handler.php like sample below

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
        $this->report($exception);

        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException ||
            $exception->getCode() == 403 ||
            $exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            if (!is_admin_site()) {
                 return view('user.403');
            }
            return view('admin.403');
        }

        if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
            return view('admin.501');
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```